# Why is authenticated (form-based) UIWebView not keeping authentication data after NSURLConnection is issued from delegate?

Tags: cookies, delegates

My UIWebView loads a website with a login form. After logging-in the user authenticates just fine and a UIWebViewDelegate delegate executes an NSURLConnection (successfully). After that, the site asks again for login.

If I move the NSURLConnection request inside the viewDidLoad, everything goes just fine, but I need to have it in the delegate to check for a specific url change to fire the post.

Do I have it completely wrong? I have been messing with cookies and sessions trying to see why I am logged out again and again with no luck at all.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This article relates to [Losing authentication after NSURLConnection executes in delegate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20036447/losing-authentication-after-nsurlconnection-executes-in-delegate)

In short, Code Igniter uses a function that destroys user-agent header causing the app to logout.